# Find a orthogonal basis with a specific inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have V = {s: {1,2,3} -> R} (R vectorial space of functions of set {1,2,3} to reals, ((s is a function))) . Then we define h: V x V -> R:

---

h(s,t) = 9s(1)t(1) + 3s(2)t(1) + 3s(1)t(2) + 2s(2)t(2) + 3s(3)t(3)

---

I) Give an orthogonal basis of V for the inner product above, whose first element is the function f with values ​​s(1)=1, s(2)= 1, s(3) =1

---

I've been trying to solve this problem for days but I can't find how to solve it. I was able to prove that h  is an inner product and I was trying to use Gram Schmidt to find the orthogonal basis, but I can't get any further (I don't know how many elements the orthogonal basis will have and how to calculate it). Note: I know how the orthogonal base is usually calculated, but in this exercise I can't figure out how to use the inner product that I've been given. Also, how should I write the first element of the basis? (1,1,1)? or just "s" (and I clarify what values ​​this function takes when it is evaluated at 1,2 and 3)?
I would appreciate a hint and if you know a book where to find similar exercises.

Comment: it might be useful to first establish an isomorphism of $V$ with $\mathbb R^3$ (just send $f\in V$ to the vector $(f(1),f(2),f(3))$).

Comment: [MSE-$\tt MathJax$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please, read that. It´ll improve your posts quality.

Comment: @GiulioR That makes sense. So I could define the first element as (1,1,1). Then, to calculate the second element of the orthogonal basis, I could create two new functions that assign other values, for example s´(1) =1, s´(2) = 2, s´(3) = 3
and s*(1)=2 s*(2)=2, s*(3) =3 Then I have the vectors (1,2,3) and (2,2,3) and (1,1,1) ( linearly independent). Can I now use these to calculate the orthogonal basis? considering (1,1,1) as the first vector of the orthogonal basis?

Comment: @FelixMarin I´ll edit it later and I´ll use MathJax!

Comment: Fine. Thanks.$\mbox{}$

Comment: yes, that looks like a sensible approach